# Firebase Admin SDK verifySessionCookie does not authenticate user for Firebase Storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am using session cookies as especified in this [link in the Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies). Using the session cookie I am able to authenticate the user in the server for Server Side Rendering of protected routes of my React Web App. But the docs recommend setting persistance of client side authentication to none in order to handle persistance with the cookie. I get the point of that, but the problem is that my app also uses Firebase Storage, and if a user logins, then refreshes the page, verifySessionCookie runs in the server, app get user data BUT user is not authenticated for Firebase Storage and cannot upload files to it.

Is there a way the Admin SDK can verify the session cookie and authenticate the user for storage access?

Comment: You can instead run the firebase storage operation from your server. You send the request to your server and verify the session cookie and then use the Firebase admin SDK to complete the storage operation from there.

Comment: @bojeil Yes, I guess that makes sense. Keep all firebase logic in the server and make requests with good old axios.

Comment: Since your system depends on server side cookies for authenticated requests, I think that is the way to go here too.